# Dynamic Thematic Map

Tags: vba, dictionary

For those who have worked with thematic (choropleth), has anybody made it "dynamic?"

I've created a VBA thematic map by tying production data from each state to a map of the US. However, the result is a static map that only shows one data set (in the case of this example, each year for all states).

Below is the code:

```
Dim y
Dim T1 As Long
Dim T2 As Long
Dim T3 As Long
Dim T4 As Long
Dim T5 As Long

y = 1
T1 = 0
T2 = 5
T3 = 10
T4 = 15
T5 = 20
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("C6:C53") 'The data points on each state for the year 2009,    where columns D, E, F, G are 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, respectively.
If cell.Value = T1 Then
Sheets("Map").Shapes(y).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
ElseIf cell.Value <= T2 And cell.Value > T1 Then
Sheets("Map").Shapes(y).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(250, 249, 232)
ElseIf cell.Value <= T3 And cell.Value > T2 Then
Sheets("Map").Shapes(y).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(247, 245, 218)
ElseIf cell.Value <= T4 And cell.Value > T3 Then
Sheets("Map").Shapes(y).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(237, 233, 180)
ElseIf cell.Value <= T5 And cell.Value > T4 Then
Sheets("Map").Shapes(y).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(232, 226, 140)
ElseIf cell.Value > T5 Then
Sheets("Map").Shapes(y).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(224, 216, 96)
End If

y = y + 1

Next
```

I've added a scroll bar with 2009 as the minimum value and 2013 as the maximum, linking the value of the scroll to a cell (say, cell C30).

I'd like to automate the map by scrolling through the bar and have the map "shift" each annual set of data in response to the linked cell (C30).

Is this possible? Does anybody here have an approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

I can work this if you can send me a Sample of excel working that you have worked on it so far. Please send as an attachment to email id : summer12in@yahoo.com

Thanks...